# How to disable automatic check out from Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Whenever I open any solution in VS2012 from local path (which is mapped in TFS), the files are automatically checking out. I want to disable this feature.

I tried to disconnect from TFS and to work on it, But it is closing the solution. Plesase help me out in achieving this. I didn't get this problem before when I was using VS2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unbind your project(s) from TFS source control.

1. Select the project or solution from the Solution Explorer
2. From the main menu select File->Source Control->Advanced->Change Source Control...
3. Select one or all projects and press the "Unbind" button on the top of the dialog
4. select ok to the warning popup

You can later bind the projects again, personally I don't do this so I can't say how well it works. I found some more info [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1a3586a-fb04-4d75-ad10-148b1c8941e7/how-to-unbind-project-in-visual-studio-2012-from-tfs2012?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

Here are the visual steps:
[image: Step 2]

This brings up the dialog to select projects to bind/unbind.
I had to select one at a time.

[image: Step 3]
Select "Unbind" for each project

[image: step 4]

Here's what it should look like when unbound.
[image]

You can later come back and bind the projects again and TFS will try and reconcile your changes.

Comment: Thanks, Worked very well

Answer (score 2):

Try rather change Checked-in items (Saving, Editing) to 'Prompt for check out'

Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Enviroment -> Checked-in items

Answer (score 0):

Disable the following option. It should solve your problem.

```
Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Enviroment -> Get everything when a solution or project is opened
```

[image]

Comment: From my point of view the two menue-points "Environment" and "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server" contain plenty of options which can occur you described behavior. Please check this option or post screenshots of the two menues.